# How to show data from database in dscending order in codeigniter?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, phpmyadmin, codeigniter-3

Normally when I get the data from my database I there are arranged in the order of their id.However, I have created a column called 'sales' which is also an integer
and I would like my data to be arranged in ascending order according to the *sales*.Here is my code:

**My Model**

```
     public  function get_bestseller($id = FALSE) {
    if ($id === FALSE)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('submit');
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    $query = $this->db->get_where('submit', array('id' => $id));
    $this->db->order_by('sales', 'DESC');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

**My View**

```
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="faq-cat-2">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion-cat-2">
                <?php foreach ($bestseller as $bestseller_item): ?>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img class="lazy" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>Images/last.gif"
                                 data-original="<?php echo base_url() ?>uploads/<?php echo $bestseller_item['imgname']; ?>"
                                 style="width: 350px; height: 150px">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <?php if ($bestseller_item['Price'] == 0): ?>
                                    <h4 class="pull-right"><p class="text-success">Free</p></h4>
                                <?php else: ?>
                                    <h4 class="pull-right">$<?php echo $bestseller_item['Price']; ?></h4>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <h4>
                                    <a href="<?php echo site_url('submit/view/' . $bestseller_item['id']); ?>"
                                       target="_blank"><?php echo $bestseller_item['Title']; ?></a>
                                </h4>
                                <p><?php echo $bestseller_item['textarea']; ?></p>
                            </div>
                            <p class="text-right"><b
                                        class="author">By: <?php echo $bestseller_item['Author']; ?></b>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**My Controller**

```
   public function index()
   {
    $data['bestseller'] = $this->Submit_Database->get_bestseller();

    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('pages/home', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

Comment: FYI, `DESC` means **descending**, not ascending.

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = $this->db->order_by('sales', 'DESC')->get_where('submit', array('id' => $id));
```

You are adding the order by clause after the query has already ran.

Comment: Thanks,but it is still the same the data are arranged according to id not sales.

Comment: In which order you want,ascending or descending?-@AsheshNepal

Comment: I want it to be in descending order